Movie about a wildlife adventure (probably 80s/90s)
I can't really give you a lot of details on this one.
I'll just list everything I can remember:

main characters are a group of kids/teenagers (2 of them might be brothers)
might take place in a remote town surrounded by wild nature
might be in alaska, a scandinavian country or something along those lines
the kids are bored and want to experience an adventure in the wild
they have an 8mm camera and set out to film all kinds of wild animals
sometimes they get into dangerous situations (a bear cave IIRC)
when they come back, their little movie/documentary is shown in the local cinema
probably takes place in the 80s

It's been around 6-7 years since I've seen (parts of) this if that helps, but it's most likely from the 80s or 90s.
Please don't consider any of the points to be facts as I just might remember stuff wrong or mixed up stuff with other movies.


Wild America (1997)

Three brothers - Marshall, Marty and Mark dream of becoming
  naturalists and portraying animal life of America. One summer their
  dream comes true, they travel through America, filming alligators,
  bears and moose.

From Wikipedia, some of the plot points: 

The film opens in the summer of 1967 with Marshall Stouffer being
  chased by his two older brothers, Mark and Marty. The two oldest
  brothers love using Marshall to film him in stunts, which he dislikes.
  Occasionally Marty and Mark will show footage of their antics in their
  garage to all their friends. Mark and Marty have a dream of filming
  dangerous animals around the country, and the dream starts when they
  find a rare, special camera in a shop. Agnes (their mother) loans them
  the money she was saving up and they begin planning their trip. Their
  father is against this idea.
[...]
The overall goal of the trip in Marty's mind is to find a legendary
  cave located somewhere in the western states said to be filled with
  hundreds of bears. Marty learns of it when reading an article in a
  wildlife magazine, which took it from a trapper's journal from the
  19th century.
[...]
They display their film, and everyone claps, but when their enemy DC
  makes a rude comment, their dad begins to applaud, having the crowd
  cheer and clap. Marshall and his Dad smile at each other at the end.


Read more about the movie here, here and here. Watch the trailer here.

WOW, that was fast!
Thank you so much!

No problem. Enjoy your movie!
